# Python input prompt using for loop

Tags: python-3.6

i have created a script that use user inputs to greet them by hello but it prints the alphabets not the complete name in one sentence. How?

```
val = input()

for i in val:
    print("Hello", i)
```

but this prints 
    Hello p
    Hello r
    Hello i
    Hello n
    Hello c
    Hello e

Comment: Why did you create a `for` loop? Don't you just want `print("Hello", val)`?

Comment: The loop is doing what it's supposed to, giving you each letter of the string one at a time.

Comment: Is there any way i can use for loop and input prompt? Just for learning? Print hello prince at one go?

Comment: There are lots of ways you could combine those two things, but if you don't tell us what you want your program to do, we can't help.

Comment: there is no program sir, i am learning python, i am on for loop chapter, earlier to that i have done same in def function where function greets whenever user inputs name, so i thought why not in for loop.

Comment: You're asking something like "I drew a sun, but now I want to know if there's a way to use a blue crayon." Yes, you can certainly use a blue crayon, but I don't know what more to tell you, since you didn't tell me what you're trying to draw.

Comment: There's nothing sir, it was just a thought, what if i combine for loop and input, to print hello prince? Just something to learn that's all.

Comment: Okay, I've voted to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `input()` takes in an input from the command line. For example, if you input `prince` into the command line, now the variable `val` has a value of `"prince"`.

With the for loop, you are using the for-each notation. Strings are also a type of iterator--in fact, strings are simply arrays of characters. Think of it like a regular list, but instead of having a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, you have the list `['p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'c', 'e']`. So each iteration of the for loop only prints the character it is currently iterating on.

You could simplify your code by avoiding the for loop and only using the code `print("Hello", val)`.

However, if you only want to practice with for loops, you can use the code below. Try to understand how and why you can simplify it!

```
val = input()            //stores the user input into val
name = ""                //creates an empty string called name

for s in val:            //iterates through each character in val
    name += s            //adds that character to name
                         //when the for loop ends, the user input is stored in name
print("Hello", name)     //prints "Hello" and the name
```

Comment: Any way to combine input and forloop to print("hello" val), just for learning

Comment: Well this is extremely and unnecessarily overcomplicated haha, but yes, I will edit my response because it is a bit long.

Comment: Hi, i am asking bit more, can you please explain it to me also?

Comment: Victor C. Thank you so much sir, you made my day. It is great help. You rock sir.